# 502 Bad Gateway while deploying in GAE

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, web-hosting, app.yaml

I am trying to deploy my nodejs application in Google App Engine.
But I keep on getting **502 Bad Gateway** when I run

```
$ gcloud app browse
```

This is my file structure

```
->project
  |___node_modules
  |___models
  |___routes
  |___index.js
  |___app.yaml
  |___package.json
  |___package.lock.json
  |___public
      |___index.html
      |___js
```

This is my app.yaml file

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
threadsafe: true
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

# Handle the main page by serving the index page.
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/(.*)

# Recommended file skipping declaration from the GAE tutorials
skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
  - ^(.*/)?app\.yml
  - ^(.*/)?#.*#
  - ^(.*/)?.*~
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
  - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
  - ^(.*/)?\..*
  - ^(.*/)?tests$
  - ^(.*/)?test$
  - ^test/(.*/)?
  - ^COPYING.LESSER
  - ^README\..*
  - \.gitignore
  - ^\.git/.*
  - \.*\.lint$
  - ^fabfile\.py
  - ^testrunner\.py
  - ^grunt\.js
  - ^node_modules/(.*/)?
```

**Note**: I am running on port 8080 and have included "start" : "node index.js" in package.json

Comment: I think you copied `app.yaml` incorrectly. If that is your `app.yaml` file, that's one problem.

Comment: Can you run server locally and access it on `:8080`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. It was in the index.js file.
Previously:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, "localhost",()=>{
    console.log("Server running at port " + port);
});
```

I had to replace it with:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("Server running at port " + port);
});
```