# Bad gateway when deploying dockerfile with angular in GAE

Tags: angular, docker, google-app-engine, nginx, dockerfile

Just like others [502 Bad Gateway while deploying in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101815/502-bad-gateway-while-deploying-in-gae) i too am having the same problem 502 Bad Gateway but this time, deploying an angular app through Dockerfile in GAE.

Here is my app.yaml

```
service: app-name
runtime: custom
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
```

This is the DockerFile

```
FROM node:10-alpine as buildContainer
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
COPY . /app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 8080

# Serve the app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disable-host-check

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I tried the above - with and without --disable-host-check. Though I dont really understand what it should be

All previous searches on SO pointed to nginx.conf file as being the culprit - so i copied exactly the nginx file from the GAE docs for custom runtimes

so nginx.conf is

```
events {
worker_connections 768;
}

http {
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

# Logs will appear on the Google Developer's Console when logged to this
# directory.
access_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;
error_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

server {
    # Google App Engine expects the runtime to serve HTTP traffic from
    # port 8080.
    listen 8080;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

}

Of course, the docker build and app is working fine when deployed from localhost
How is an angular web app supposed to be deployed with Docker ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but do not use `ng serve` to serve the application, it's only meant for development. Build your app and then use different tool (nginx) for serving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, you have several problems :

1- You should never use "ng-serve" for production
2- You need to build your app firs and get the dist forlder
3- Launch nginx after setting config

You need to build your app first using `ng build --prod` and configure your docker config for build.

Example of Dockerfile for an angular app :

```
FROM nginx:1.15.12-alpine

# Removing nginx default page.
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copying nginx configuration.
COPY /nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copying  source into web server root.
COPY /dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Exposing ports.
EXPOSE 80

# Starting server.
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Example for nginx config :

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

You need to understand that building Angular App gives us a folder called "dist" containing the .html file and several .js files. It is that .html file that gets served by nginx.

The `ng serve` is used for development only.

Hope it helps. Good Luck !

Comment: this is very helpful .. i am trying it. However, i on google app engine they explicitly ask to listen on 8080. Is 80 somehow a shorthand for the same port ?

Comment: Glad it helps. No port 80 is not the same as 8080. The NGINX image exposes ports 80 and 443 in the container. So you need to listen to one of them and usually we use port 80 and you can map it later in the image config.

Comment: I am still getting server error - as I am using google app engine... arent these lines building the app   `FROM node:10-alpine as buildContainer
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
COPY . /app`

Comment: As I told you, to deploy your app you need to build it locally first and copy the dist file in the docker image. What you are doing is not suitable for production. 
If you need port mapping you need to use docker-compose.